# Matrix Imputation with NuclearNormMinimization fails with TypeError

Tags: python, matrix, missing-data, fancyimpute

I am trying to impute missing values in the matrix by calling different functions from fancyimpute.py. NuclearNormMinimization runs fine for some of the matrices but fails for the example below.

`NuclearNormMinimization(verbose=False).complete(matrix)`

where
```

```
matrix = [[3.64625, 7.34375, 15.0], 
         [5.00000, 12.50000, NaN],
         [15.00000,11.25000, NaN]]
```

The error message is:

*TypeError: Expected NuclearNormMinimization.solve() to return NumPy array but got class 'NoneType'.*

I am using this approach for bigger sparse matrices, but once in a while I get a small matrix with a few missing values, and my code fails. Can somebody help me to understand why this is happening? What are assumptions for NuclearNormMinimization imputation techniques?

Comment: I would consider this a toy-implementation. It's based on off-the-shelve SOCP or SDP solver which might fail under some conditions (not that it should given your example, and not that one could directly see a problem like linear dependencies between rows or something similar). So the solvers in use are probably ECOS and SCS. You seem to use defaults, meaning ```fast_but_approximate``` which will use SCS. There is no reason ever to favor SCS to ECOS when matrices are that small (both are powerful solvers, but very different)!So try ```fast_but_approximate=False```

Comment: That being said, in the real-world (not that tiny matrix) you will want to use a specialized solver and it's not hard to implement. libmf would do NuclearNorm aka TraceNorm optimization too (and it's insanely fast). And i played with MaxNorm MF which is a bit harder to optimize, but still, a working large-scale implementation is easy to achieve (projected gradient descent). **Another question** is: how are the parameters set. There is one dominating param, the rank constraint, and to me it makes not much sense to use defaults for all imputation tasks! It's a param to tune!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try the suggestions.